# Use of "WHIRL" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

It was extremely pleasant, on the top of the hill, surrounded by chirping sparrows, flowing rivers and huge tress, my hair were flowing in the air and I whirled. I was wearing a skirt,

Can I say this? :

> I gave my skirt a nice whirl.

If I want to express this only by using the word "WHIRL", is this a correct way?

Comment: I suspect ***twirl*** might be more common for your exact context, but ***whirl*** is perfectly okay. Maybe just my opinion, but I think the more metaphoric usage *I don't know if this will work, but I'll give it a whirl* (where it just means ***a try, a go***, nothing to do with rotary motion as such) would always be ***whirl***, never ***twirl*** (which latter isn't normally used metaphorically like that).

Comment: Also, “my hair ***was*** flowing...”

Comment: I think you probably mean *huge **trees***.

Comment: Perfectly felicitous to me.

Comment: [Sure, give it a whirl.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Sure%2C+give+it+a+whirl%22)

Comment: 'I whirled' on its own reads oddly to me; I would say 'I whirled (or twirled) round'.

Comment: What does a dictionary tell you about "whirl" as a noun?

Answer (score 0):

It feels a little off to me using `whirl` in that sentence. Although there is usage for `hazelnut whirl` or any things in a spiral shape.

Some nominal uses:

> The speed of his movement left a whirl of dust in the floor
>
> His mad social whirls used to throw people off
>
> While all that happens, the little girl was just enjoying her popsicle whirl

Maybe, try to change the sentence a bit to:

> It gave my skirt a nice sense of whirl

But if it is still throwing people off (it might), perhaps just simplifying to:

> It gave my skirt a nice sense of movement

Doesn't sound fancy, but trying to sound fancy every sentence isn't ideal as well.